# Can anyone identify my breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image]It is an old mobile home and I am trying to find a replacement for the breaker.

[image]

Comment: Not from that view, no. We'd need to see any details involving writing.  It would also be good to see the panel itself, and any labeling that is on the panel. You'll need a better camera though. 240 pixels isn't going to cut it lol.

Comment: Wow, that's the best you can do?  OK, so my guess is these pictures came from the home inspector.  Yeah we won't be able to tell you anything from that.

Comment: Can you post photos of any labeling on the inside of the breaker box in question's door/cover?

Comment: Outside on a pole? Inside the MH?

Comment: A surface mounted breaker like that could be just about any brand we used to put them in Hoffman boxes as a main disconnecting breaker outside feeding the panel in the house, if the box is just a metal box with no stickers inside.  the ampacity may be embossed on the side of the handle but all the stickers were paper based back then and all of the ones I have seen the elements have faded any possible printing